# xpath find attribute by id and get the attribute parent content

Tags: xpath

I have an XML-structure that looks like this:

```
<document>
<body>
<section>
<title>something</title>
<subtitle>Something again</subtitle>
<section>
<p xml:id="1234">Some text</p>
</section>
</section>
<section>
<title>something2</title>
<subtitle>Something again2</subtitle>
<section>
<p xml:id="12345678">Some text2</p>
</section>
</section>
</body>
</document>
```

What i want to is to find search for the attribute xml:id containing 12345678 and once found, get the previous sibling (subtitle) content. Is this possible with xpath? I have this:

```
//p[contains(@xml:id,'12345678')]/preceding-sibling::subtitle
```

Comment: Note that xml:id attributes cannot start with a digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood the post correctly, for the specific query that you have put, the expected answer is `Something Again2`. You can use the following query to do this:

**UPDATED** as the document schema is changed

```
//section[section/p[@xml:id="12345678"]]/subtitle
```

Comment: @user2075124: It is working fine at my end. I am not sure how you are testing. I tried with two XPath tester Editix and XPatherizer in Notepad++ and it works fine.

Comment: Sorry. The structure above is missing a level. I've edited it now. Any suggestions on how to solve that?

Comment: Updated my answer to meet the current schema!

Comment: Any thoughts on how to to get the xml:id from another attribute? Like: //section[section/p[@xml:id=@xmlidentifier]]/subtitle